# Add multiple UIButton from Array and screenboud

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, uibutton

i need to create dynamic button using array elements.
Also button are row wise in increasing order like

```
2 button
3 button
4 button
5 button
```

My code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

    btn_array=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    [btn_array addObject:@"Deepak Singh"];
    [btn_array addObject:@"Vikas Singh"];
    [btn_array addObject:@"Vipin Rawat"];
    [btn_array addObject:@"Deepak"];
    [btn_array addObject:@"Singh"];
    [btn_array addObject:@"Rawat"];
    [btn_array addObject:@"Vinita rawat"];
    [btn_array addObject:@"Vinod"];
    [btn_array addObject:@"OOP"];

    [self drawButtonsFromArray:btn_array];

      [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}



-(void)drawButtonsFromArray:(NSArray*)arr

{
    UIScreen *mainScreen = [UIScreen mainScreen];


    int x=20 ,y=100;

      for (int i=0; i<[arr count]; i++)
      {
          UIButton *btn=[[UIButton alloc]init];
          CGSize stringsize = [[arr objectAtIndex:i] sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:14]];
          [btn setTitle:[arr objectAtIndex:i] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
          [btn setTitle:[arr objectAtIndex:i] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
          [btn setTitle:[arr objectAtIndex:i] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
          CALayer *btnLayer = [btn layer];
          [btnLayer setMasksToBounds:YES];
          [btnLayer setCornerRadius:10.0f];
          [btn setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
          btn.titleLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;


          [btn setFrame:CGRectMake(x,y,stringsize.width, 25)];

          int ww=x+btn.frame.size.width;

          NSLog(@"X=====%d ",x);

          NSLog(@"ww=====%d ",ww);

          if (ww>=mainScreen.bounds.size.width) {

           x=20;
           y=y+35;
               //[btn setFrame:CGRectMake(x,y,stringsize.width+15, 25)];

          }
          else
          {

              x=x+btn.frame.size.width+5;

          }
          [self.view addSubview:btn];


      }


}
```

My output shows [image]

Comment: I'm not quite certain what your question is. To rephrase, are you simply wanting a display of buttons (which each will display the name text as the button titles) in rows, where the first row has 2buttons, then the second row has 3 buttons, 3rd has 4 buttons etc?

Comment: yes correct i need same

Comment: In that case, rather than create UIButtons, would you not be better using a UICollectionView, printing the name on each UICollectionViewCell and using the didSelectItemAtIndexPath: method to detect they have been pressed? The method you use 'sizeWithFont' is deprecated too, this needs to be changed to boundingRectWithSize method. Using a UICollectionView, you will be able to place the cells in rows you desire much easier.

Comment: Definitely use a UICollectionView to make this easier.

Answer (score 0):

look this demo 
[https://github.com/ChenYilong/CollectionViewClassifyMenu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hd1Rq.png)

run the demo like the two picture ,I Hope it  can help you

[image]
[image]